# Trying to call a web service in java, after setting certificate and keystore

Tags: java, web-services

Trying to make a simple web service call... it seems like it should be a simple task but no, it's a pain. I thought it would require my cert and then everything would be ok, but I am wrong. Here is the code I was using, but I have no idea how to proceed with the next step of calling the actual web service:

```
https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?$top=5
```

and then iterating over the json data.

CODE:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.log4j.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500PrivateCredential;

/**
 * A sample program that demonstrates how:
 * to view Data from the ADP web service
 */
public class ImportADP {            

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ImportADP importAdp = new ImportADP();
    importAdp.initLog4J();

    try {
        System.out.println("Start");

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
        CertificateFactory cf = null;
        Certificate cert = null;
        try {
            fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("cc.jks");
            ks.load(fis, "password".toCharArray());

            System.out.println("jks loaded.. woohoo");

            FileInputStream certIs = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/david.bekkerus/Desktop/y/cc.crt");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(certIs);

            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);

            System.out.println("cert made");
            System.out.println("cert set");

        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
                //certIs.close();
            }
        }

        final char[] KEY_PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();

        final KeyManagerFactory kmf = 
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

        kmf.init(ks, KEY_PASSWORD);          

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = 
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);

        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(
            kmf.getKeyManagers(), 
            tmf.getTrustManagers(), 
            new java.security.SecureRandom());  

        SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);

        URL url = new URL(tokenServerUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();            
        System.out.println("connection: " + conn.toString());


        System.out.println("perm:"+ conn.getPermission());

        //System.out.println("httpGet:"+ httpPost(tokenServerUrl, clientID.toCharArray(), clientSecret.toCharArray()));

        /** this is the problem... always pukes here */
        conn.getResponseMessage();

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    logger.info("End time: " + new java.util.Date() );

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have the wsdl for the web service you are trying to call? That is the key element.

Comment: Not yet... requesting that. This would be something created by the company that makes the web service?

Comment: Yes. There's not much you can do without it.

Comment: I am lost very lost on this code... I am not sure what do to anymore. I tried for over a week solid. I got as close I think. step 1) connection setup step 2) my_file.crt is added to my local cacert file in my JRE, but 3) I cannot get the data returned from the connection. It fails at : conn.getResponseMessage()

Comment: Error: 
C:\Users\david.bekkerus\Desktop\y>java ImportADP -Djavax.net.debug=SSL
Start
jks loaded.. woohoo
cert made
cert set
connection: sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials
perm:("java.net.SocketPermission" "accounts.adp.com:80" "connect,resolve")
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Generally this error means the certificate is not found in your trustore. Are you sure you added the certificate in the trustore ?

Comment: I performed this command... keytool -keystore C:/java8/jre/lib/security/cacerts -import -alias "CC Mutual SSL" -file C:/Users/david.bekkerus/Desktop/y/cc.crt and followed the entry and it said added... then I did this: keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/cacerts  > java_cacerts.txt and looked at the file... and saw my entry in the cert.

Comment: how do you run your program  ? If you use an IDE, check that you use the correct jdk (which should be placed in C:/java8 according to your previous post)

Comment: I run this app in cmd... java ImportADP appears it is using my right jdk C:\Users\david.bekkerus\Desktop\y>java -verbose
[Opened C:\java8\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\java8\jre\lib\rt.jar]

Comment: check the JAVA_HOME environment variable, maybe you have to add the certificate in the trustore jdk1.8.xx/jre/secuity/cacerts

Comment: When to my env variables... my JAVA_HOME = c:\java8   That is all I have there... do I need to add ;C:\java8\jre\lib\security\cacerts to the entry?

Comment: I also tried running this with 
>java ImportADP -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore  

got the same error as before : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification

Comment: Guess it is hopeless...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get ADP to sign your cert.  That is what we had to do.